# Thread .getName method, is not displaying accurate/desired thread name

Tags: java, multithreading

Can you help me understand why the name of the thread when executing the methods `put()`, and `get()`, is still `main thread`, and not `Producer1`, and `Consumer1` respectively.

Goal: Solution in order to have the name of the threads respectively as: `Producer1`, and `Consumer1` or explanation as to why this is happening.

More descriptive goal:

Producer1, Put 0
Consumer1, List is empty!

Producer1, Put 1
Consumer1, Got: [0,1]
Consumer1, Consumed: "1"

And so on...

Errors: No errors, just not desired outcome:

main thread, Put 0
main thread, List is empty!

main thread, Put 1
main thread, Got: [0,1]
main thread, Consumed: "1"

Attempts: I have also tried the `join` method that is commented on the Main class, but the end-result is the same.

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q queue = new Q();

        Producer producer1 = new Producer(queue, "Producer1");
        //Producer producer2 = new Producer(queue, "Producer2");      

        Consumer consumer1 = new Consumer(queue, "Consumer1");

        producer1.thread.start();
        //producer2.thread.start();

        consumer1.thread.start();

        /*
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
            producer1.thread.join();
            //producer2.thread.join();
            consumer1.thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Q:

```
public class Q {
    //int n;
    boolean ready = false;
    List<Integer> products;
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

    Q(){
      products = new ArrayList<>(5);
    }

    // ------------------------
    synchronized void put(int n){
        while (ready){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(t.getName() + " was interrupted!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        if(products.size() < 5){
            this.products.add(n);
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " thread, Put: " +  n);
            ready = true;
            notify();
        } else {
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " thread, List is full!");
            ready = true;
            notify();
        }
        //this.n = n;
    }

    // ------------------------
    synchronized List<Integer> get(){
        while (!ready){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(t.getName() + " thread was interrupted!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        if(products.size() > 1){
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " thread, Got: " + products);
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " thread, Consumed: \"" + (products.get(products.size() - 1)) + "\"");
            removeLastElement();
            ready = false;
            notify();
        } else {
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " thread, List is empty!");
            ready = false;
            notify();
        }

        //System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        //ready = false;
        //notify();
        return products;
    }

    void removeLastElement(){
        int index = (this.products.size() - 1);
        this.products.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Producer:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{
    Q queue;
    Thread thread;

    Producer(Q queue, String threadName){
        thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
        System.out.println("Test: " + thread.getName());
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            queue.put(i++);
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{
    Q queue;
    Thread thread;

    Consumer(Q queue, String threadName){
        thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
        System.out.println("Test: " + thread.getName());
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            queue.get();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you assist?
Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use images for text.

Comment: @aled apologies, I have removed it, and added text instead.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Q`'s field `Thread t` is being assigned `Thread.currentThread()` when an instance of `Q` is created, and a `Q` is being created on your main thread. So `t` references the main thread from the very beginning.

Instead, remove `Thread t` and replace all instances of `t.getName()` with `Thread.currentThread().getName()`. This will directly retrieve the name of the thread that is actually making calls to methods of `Q` at runtime.

(Or, you can just declare `Thread t = Thread.currentThread()` within each method instead. It will be assigned the "current thread" which in that case would be the one calling the method.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow by that I meant: move the entire statement `Thread t = Thread.currentThread();` into method scope so that is assigned at method execution time instead of object creation time.